# Customer in line queue implementation

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to program a project in C# , for customer in line checkout simulation. 
Basically I get input of numbers of checkout station open, number of customers to assign them and number of products each customer has. I know i have to implement using queues. Any samples or examples to how to implement it. Thank you for your replys.

Comment: sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

Answer (score 0):

I would look on ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) such as [MassTransit project](http://masstransit-project.com/) to accomplish something like that. They have some great examples that fit your case.